# GRPC: Client streaming with configuration message

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

Here's a proto definition for a service that consumes a stream of events
from a client

```
message Event {
  // ...
}

service EventService {
  rpc Publisher(stream Event) returns (google.protobuf.Empty);
}
```

The problem is that the server needs to be told what to do with this stream.
Ideally, it would first recieve an `Options` message:

```
message Event {
  // ...
}

message Options {
  // ...
}

service EventService {
  rpc Publisher(Options, stream Event) returns (google.protobuf.Empty);
}
```

However, grpc only supports one parameter for `rpc` methods.
One solution is to introduce an additional `PublishMessage` message which
can contain either an `Options` or `Event` message.

```
message PublishMessage {
  oneof content {
    Options options = 1;
    Event event = 2;
  }
}
```

The service would then expect the first `PublishMessage` to contain an `Options` message, with all subsequent ones containing `Event` messages. This introduces additional overhead from the wrapping message and makes the api a little clunky.

Is there a cleaner way to achieve the same result?

Comment: how about put the `option` in request metadata?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `oneof` is the suggested approach when many fields or messages are in play. The overhead is minimal, so wouldn't generally be a concern. There is the clunkiness though.

If there's only a few fields, you may want to combine the fields from Options and Event into a single message. Or similarly add Options to Event as a field. You'd expect the Options fields to be present on the first request and missing from subsequent. This works better when there's fewer configuration fields, like just a "name."