# Protobuf: streaming input with common data to all elements

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

Below is the service spec:

```
service Cooler {
    rpc saveThing (stream SaveRequest) returns (SaveReply);
}
```

I need to stream messages to to `Cooler.saveThing()`. All the `SaveRequests` have a common field `author` and unique fields per a `Thing` are `price` and `name`. How can I send the `author` only once?

#### Not working attempt - Multiple inputs

It would be a solution but it is not supported by protobuf yet.

```
service Cooler {
    rpc saveThing (stream SaveRequest, Author) returns (SaveReply);
}
```

#### Not working attempt - Nested message

Every received element of `SaveRequest` will still contain `author` and an array of `Things`.

```
message SaveRequest {
  message Thing {
    int price = 1;
    string name = 2;
  }

  repeated Thing things = 1;
  string author = 2;
}
```

#### Possible solution

Grpc headers.

## Question

How can I send the `author` only once?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GRPC: Client streaming with configuration message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230577/grpc-client-streaming-with-configuration-message)