# Sending protobuf-encoded metadata with a stream

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, rpc

Questions about attaching a piece of metadata (an "initial" request) when initiating a client-side streaming gRPC have already been asked before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230577/grpc-client-streaming-with-configuration-message), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62796168/best-practice-for-defining-grpc-metadata-about-a-stream)), but some answers are suggesting that it's not possible and suggest using `oneof` where first request towards a server contains the metadata in question, and subsequent requests contain the actual data to be processed by the server. I'm wondering if it's safe to encode metadata with a binary encoding of choice and send it to the server where it can be extracted from the `Context` object and deserialized back into meaningful data. I'm fairly certain that it's perfectly fine when it comes to text-based encodings such as JSON. But what about protobuf? Assuming we define our service like so:

```protobuf
service MyService {
  rpc ChitChat (stream ChatMessage) returns (stream ChatMessage);
}

message ChatMessage {
  // ...
}

message Meta {
  // ...
}
```

We can include a `Meta` object in the request:

```golang
meta := &pb.Meta{
    // ...
}
metab, err := proto.Marshal(meta)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("marshaling error: %v", err)
}
newCtx := metadata.NewOutgoingContext(context.Background(), metadata.Pairs("meta-bin", string(metab)))
// ...ChitChat(newCtx)
```

And access it on the server side:

```golang
func (s *server) ChitChat(stream pb.MyService_ChitChatServer) error {
    md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(stream.Context())
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("no metadata received")
    }
    metaStr := md.Get("meta-bin")
    if len(metaStr) != 1 {
        return fmt.Errorf("expected 1 md; got: %v", len(metaStr))
    }
    meta := new(pb.Meta)
    if err := proto.Unmarshal([]byte(metaStr[0]), meta); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error during deserialization: %v", err)
    }

    // ...
    return nil
}
```

It appears to be working quite well - am I missing something? How easy is it to shoot yourself in the foot with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, gRPC supports binary headers, so this approach isn't *invalid*; it is a little less clear that it is expected, but then: that's true for the `oneof` approach too, so ... not much difference there.